# How do I display multiple text lines in an <asp:BoundFleid> for an <asp:GridView> control in ASP.Net?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have the following GridView defined in an ASP.Net page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Station" HeaderText="Station" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" SortExpression="Station" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Item1" HeaderText="Main Pos. at Station" HeaderStyle-Width="10%" SortExpression="Item1" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Max1" HeaderText="Max1" SortExpression="Max1" HeaderStyle-Width="5%" />
  </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

The DataSource is defined by the following:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AppDBConnection %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT [Station], [Item1], [Max1], FROM [tblSomeTable]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The Fields Item1 and Max1 contain comma separated lists, such that:

```
Item1="N100,N200,N300,N400"
Max1="70,80,90,100"
```

The issue is that I'd like to be able split the comma separated lists in to a list of separate items and display them within the BoundField, so that each entry is on a separate line.

```
Item1   Max1
N100    70
N200    80
N300    90
N400    100
```

What is the best way to accomplish this so that I can ensure that each item appears on it's own line within the grid cell?

Should I replace the commas (,) with spaces and use a stored procedure rather than inline SQL. (I could not get the Replace() function to work in the inline SQL).

I've tried turning wordwrap on for the column, but that did not seem to work.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks,JohnB

Comment: storing data in a database as a comma separated string is a bad idea, as you have noticed. But you need to retreive the data, process it into something with rows (DataTable, List) and bind it to the GridView.

Answer (score 0):

**edit**
 I guess these code should help you a little bit: you should retrieve your results into string and split them to create a datatable. and then you can bind your gridview.

```
Dim itemResult As String 
'Query your database to add results from column Item in that string'

Dim max1Result As String 
'Query your database to add results from column Max1 in that string'


'Splitting the Strings'
Dim items as String = output.Split(New Char() {","c})
Dim max as String = output.Split(New Char() {","c})

'Adding the splitted string to Datatable'
Dim table As New System.Data.DataTable()
plt.Columns.Add("Item1")
plt.Columns.Add("Max1")

Dim newRow As DataRow 

for index As Int32 = 0 To items.Length -1
    newRow = new DataRow(items[index], max[index])
    table.Rows.Add(newRow)
Next

'Binding the gridView'
gv1.dataSource=table
gv1.DataBind()
```

**Original**

You can try to create a stored Procedure to retrieve the data from your DataBase, and populate the GridView from code behind like this:

```
Private Sub BindGridView()
    gv1.dataSource = yourStoredProcedure
    gv1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

you will call this method whenever you want to populate the GridView

Comment: What do I do in the stored proc? Do I substitute the commas with carriage returns? with spaces? What additional changes should I be making to the BoundField definition?

Comment: Nothing Special, Select [Station], [Item1],[Max1] from SomeTable will just do it. Note that I removed the last coma before the From statement.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not following. Stored Proc or dynamic sql embedded in the page will produce the same results; a comma separated list. How does this address displaying the list in a single BoundField with each element on it's own line? Thx

Comment: are your data stored as coma separated string? and which database server are you using? SQL-Server? and which version 2016 or higher?  if your data are stored as coma separated string, you will be forced to use a split function

Comment: Please re-read my description above. The data is stored as a comma separated string. The backend DB is SQL Server. Remember I'm not trying to create multiple rows based on the split string in the GridView. I have a string that is comma separated; I'm pulling that string from the DB and I would like it to be displayed in a single BoundField with each item on a separate line. Massaging in the stored proc will remove commas and potentially substitute them with other characters if need be. How do I get these to show up on separate lines with the grid cell? Thanks

Comment: I Edited my answer. Hope this will help you

Comment: stanlagtan: This is still not correct and does not address the requirements. Your solution produces a data table where each item/max is a new row in that data table. I would like to maintain the current table structure, alter the text assigned to the BoundField so each item is on a separate line within that column. Is this possible?